# Connecting Apache and Tomcat using mod_proxy_ajp works but JDBC then fails

Tags: apache, tomcat, jdbc, mod-proxy, ajp

I have a working Apache 2.2.16 on Debian Squeeze that serves some PHP applications from /var/www/ using different domains (e.g. phpApp1.com, phpApp2.com).

I also have a working Tomcat 7.x that lives in /opt/tomcat/ and servers a JSF+JPA application that lives in /opt/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/.

So MyApp can be accessed through e.g. myapp.com:8080/MyApp/home.html or phpApp1.com:8080/MyApp/home.html (because of the port). Since I wanted this to be myapp.com/home.html instead, I connected Apache and Tomcat using mod_proxy_ajp using the following config files:

An Apache virtual host in /etc/apache2/sites-available/MyApp

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias *.myapp.com
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
</Virtualhost>
```

And a Tomcat virtual host in /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Host name="myapp.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" reloadable="true" debug="0" docBase="MyApp" />
    <Alias>www.myapp.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

This works to the point that I cann access http://myapp.com/home.html and get a correct html page including css, images and js. So the AJP connector in tomcat should work.

BUT the app fails to establish a JDBC connection that otherwise works fine. It does not matter whether i use myapp.com or myapp.com:8080, it fails either way. However, it works if I access my app throug http://phpapp1.com:8080/MyApp/home.html. It only fails when I use the proxy-domain "myapp.com".

Has anyone experienced similar problems when using AJP and JDBC? How can I solve this? I had the same problem when using mod_jk, which makes use of AJP, too. Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

@Mark Rotteveel: What do you mean by "connecting directly"? I mean the JDBC connection is working if I use one of the domains that are not listed as virtual hosts in tomcats server.xml.

Here is the connection error:

```
ERROR: HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:367)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:304)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:293)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:492)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
at com.myapp.util.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:70)
at com.myapp.util.database.Database.<clinit>(Database.java:38)
at com.myapp.controller.file.UploadBacking.ajaxUpload(UploadBacking.java:89)
at com.myapp.controller.file.UploadBacking$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.ajaxUpload(UploadBacking$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxHandler$AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:495)
at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:57)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:405)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:103)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1028)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1375)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:253)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
... 60 more
```

From Database.java:

```
private Database() {
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp_persistence_unit");
}
```

MyApp/META-INF/context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Context>

<Context>

<Resource
    name="jdbc/db_myapp" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    username="user_myapp" 
    password="##########"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_myapp?autoReconnect=true"
    validationQuery="select 1"
    maxActive="15" 
    maxIdle="3" />

<Valve
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    directory="logs/myapp"
    prefix="myapp_access_"
    suffix=".log"
    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
    resolveHosts="false" />

</Context>
```

From WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db_myapp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And finally WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="myapp_persistence_unit">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/db_myapp" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: The use of AJP is probably not related to the JDBC problem at all. I would expect you will get the exact same error if you would connect to tomcat directly. It would be more helpful if you post the actual error you get and relevant errors in the tomcat logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work. If you create a virtual host in tomcat, you have to put an exact copy of your applications `/META-INF/context.xml` into `/tomcat/conf/Catalina/domain.com/` and name it `context.xml.default`. Well, I don't know if this is always the case, but for my setting it was. So these are my current config files that do the job:

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com`

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / ajp://my.server.ip:8009/
</Virtualhost>
```

`/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

```
<Host name="domain.com">
    <Context path="" docBase="MyApp" />
    <Alias>www.domain.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

I tried this after reading [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/86226/Tomcat/Accessing-context-xml-virtualhost) on coderanch.com from 2006 (the authors solution is in the last post). I did not change the `web.xml` or `context.xml` since this was not a misconfiguration of the `<Resource>` element. Anyway, thanks for your attempts to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `mysql-connector-j.x.y.z.jar` file in exactly one place: Tomcat's `lib` directory. Make sure you don't have a stray copy in any of your webapps' `WEB-INF/lib directories`.

Two unrelated tips:

1. Don't use `autoReconnect`
2. Use `/* ping */ SELECT 1` as your validation query: recent versions of Connector/J will use a lightweight "ping" instead of actually issuing a query in order to test a connection's validity

Comment: I already double checked that, I've got /opt/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar and no other driver in WEB-INF/lib. Thanks for the other tips though :)

Comment: The error message `Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'` has always resulted from a misconfiguration of the `<Resource>` element or a missing/duplicate JDBC library JAR file.